# Query Specific Object Inside MongoDB Document And Retrieve Only That Object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How Can I Query Specific Object Inside MongoDB Document And Retrieve Only That Object

Document:

`{
    "_id" : "mac_table",
    "00:50:56:84:c8:1b" : {
        "switch_port" : "ethernet1/37",
        "mac_ip_routed_by" : "or1-befw02",
        "mac_switch" : "adsfasfd",
        "mac_ip" : "ddsfa",
        "switch_port_description" : "asdfsafsfda",
        "mac_ip_dns" : "asdfsafd",
        "switch_port_mode" : "trunk",
        "mac_vlan:" : "3362"
    },
    "00:50:56:84:c8:1f" : {
        "switch_port" : "ethernet1/13",
        "mac_ip_routed_by" : "asdf",
        "mac_switch" : "dfdsfd",
        "mac_ip" : "asdfasdf",
        "switch_port_description" : "adsfasdf",
        "mac_ip_dns" : "asdfasfd",
        "switch_port_mode" : "trunk",
        "mac_vlan:" : "3201"
    },
    "00:50:56:a5:64:f0" : {
        "switch_port" : "",
        "mac_ip_routed_by" : "adsfdfsa",
        "mac_switch" : "",
        "mac_vlan" : "",
        "mac_ip" : "adsfasdf",
        "switch_port_description" : "",
        "mac_ip_dns" : "adadfsadf",
        "switch_port_mode" : "asdsadf"
    },
    "18:a9:05:65:43:12" : {
        "switch_port" : "ethernet116/1/6",
        "mac_ip_routed_by" : "nvvvvvv",
        "mac_switch" : "aaana",
        "mac_ip" : "10.40.77.60",
        "switch_port_description" : "test",
        "mac_ip_dns" : "test",
        "switch_port_mode" : "access",
        "mac_vlan:" : "76"
    }
}`

I want to retrieve only:

`"00:50:56:84:c8:1b" : {
        "switch_port" : "ethernet1/37",
        "mac_ip_routed_by" : "or1-befw02",
        "mac_switch" : "adsfasfd",
        "mac_ip" : "ddsfa",
        "switch_port_description" : "asdfsafsfda",
        "mac_ip_dns" : "asdfsafd",
        "switch_port_mode" : "trunk",
        "mac_vlan:" : "3362"
    }`

With every query I try, it returns the entire document, and I have about 30K objects inside this single document. If I am structuring the data incorrectly, please advise on how to better structure the data in order to get the query I need. I am concerned about adding 30K documents vs 1 document with 30k objects.

Comment: Change the document to key value pairs and you can pass key to get the key value pair. This will help you with future queries and updates and works well with mongodb database. Something like `{'_id:"mac_table", "kvp":[{"k":"00:50:56:84:c8:1b", "v":{"switch_port":...}}, other key value pairs]}`. To get the value for a key you can use `db.collection_name.find({}, {"kvp":{"$elemMatch":{"k":"00:50:56:84:c8:1b"}}})`

Comment: @veeram Agreed, I may try to modify this later for that purpose, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply use a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) like this:

```
db.collection.find({}, { "00:50:56:84:c8:1b": 1 })
```